# Passing parameter values

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2012

I have two parameters that give a date `From` and `To`.

I have two datasets that have the dates in the same format, but use two different dimensions. They both provide, Calendar Year, Calendar Month and Period.

I am trying to pass the value of the two parameters to two hidden parameters for the second dataset. I am not getting the expected data.

For example, I am passing 2017 and 2018 as `From` and `To`, but when this is passed to the hidden parameters, I am getting back the value for previous years as well.

Can someone post how they would pass a parameter value to a hidden parameter as I am clearly doing it wrong.

When setting up the hidden parameters, I am choosing to get `default` and `available` values from the visible parameters that appear in the dataset drop down list. Value field is `ParameterValue`. Label field is `ParameterCaptionIndented` but I am unsure what this is actually doing.

**Following suggestion, have tried this**

value will not update when parameters are changed

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the parameters `From` and `To` also for the second dataset?

Comment: @WolfgangKais I have to use two different date dimensions which both have the same date properties, Calendar Year, Calendar Month and Period. They have different names though. I am trying to pass the values from `From` and `To` to the hidden parameters for dataset 2.

Comment: That answers the question "why do you use 2 datasets" which I did not ask.

Comment: @WolfgangKais the only way I can currently get the data returned accurately, involves having a `from` and `to` parameter for both datasets, which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If both datasets are to use the same parameter values, there is no need to create two sets of parameters and awkwardly try to pass the value from one parameter to another.

If the parameters of your second dataset have different names, no problem, the *Dataset Properties* window contains a *Parameters* page that allows you to map the dataset parameters to your existing parameters, so you can re-use the visible parameters created for the first dataset and remove the other 2 parameters that were probably created automatically.

Comment: Ok, so I have removed the second parameters from the report, and then having selected parameters from the dataset properties menu for the second dataset, I have added the parameters from the first dataset. This works when the report is first run, but if I try and change the dates then the value i need from the second dataset does not update.

Comment: Remember that you have to click the "View Report" button after changing the parameter values. What appears in the "Parameter Value" column on the parameter mapping screen of your second dataset?

Comment: Yes, When i click view report the value stays the same. In the parameter value column i have [@From] and the second one is [@To], these are available from a drop down menu of available parameters.

Comment: Ok, then everything is correctly set up, the second dataset must refresh. If your values do not reflect the change, then maybe there's something wrong with your calculation/expression that reads from the second dataset. For testing purposes, try to use 4 separate (visible) parameters and see if the calculation is correct.

Comment: When i use 4 seperate parameters, the values are correct and update when i change them. If i delete the second set of parameters and then go to the parameter option on the second dataset properties, and add the two available parameters from the first dataset then it will not update.

Comment: Please see image above for current setup.

Comment: Well, that's indeed strange, and I don't have any clue how to fix that. How is the Credits dataset used in the report/expressions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180344/discussion-between-neal1581-and-wolfgang-kais).